# SQL Stored Procedure times out in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

The following SP times out when executed from Access VBA.  It works fine when executed from the management console.  If relevant, the server does has a high ping time:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, param As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim stMessage As String


Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server01;DATABASE=db_a;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

cnn.Open cnn.ConnectionString

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    cmd.CommandText = "we_ci_db.stprUpdateValuesInitial_A"

    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@DataSet", adInteger, adParamInput, , stDataSet)
    cmd.Parameters.Append param

    rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic

    Set rs = cmd.Execute


exit1:
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Exit Function
```

Comment: It updates a number of fields in a single table, some of the updates require the retrieval of values from functions.

Comment: Not a clue, it was the first code that I found that worked.  Note that it returns some basic info on how successful the SP was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the timeout using `CommandTimeout` property of `ADODB.Command` objects:

```
// set a very high number of seconds before timeout
cmd.CommandTimeout = 9999999
```

Comment: I misread the question the first time, so I updated the answer above for ADO

Comment: I wouldn't want to go for an infinite value in case I mess up the code and it hogs the server.  I started at 5 (seconds) and worked up.  60 seconds works fine, so I put 90 for good measure.  But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.